# Azure Data Sync Stop working btw two Azure SQL Databases (without showing error msg )

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I use Azure Data Sync to synchronize 2 Azure SQL Databases for 2 Tables, the synchronization works always good for 6-7 days , but I think every time when I make a new Deployment in the release pipeline (in azure devops) without changing anything in those 3 Tables the synchronization group stop working.

The Synchronisation group status is still showing "Good" when the Synchronisation doesn't work. I also tried to start the synchronization manually by clicking the button Sync, but nothing happens.

Now, I have always to delete the Sync Group when its not working and create a new one for the same the tables to make everything work again.

I would like to know why the Synchronization stops working.
Does anyone run into the same problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: you use data sync to sync two tables, why you say " without changing anything in those 3 Tables the synchronization group"? It really confused us. Why are you affirm the sync group not work?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick replay. Sorry, I mean without changing the schema for the two tables (not 3) let's call them table User, and table Client. The sync group works fine at the begining for couple of days, and then it stops working ( for example, if I add a new entries in the table User in DB1, it doesn't update table User in DB2 anymore -- the same for table Client in both DBs) what can be the cause of that ?  

Just for more info., we are devolopping a Web App and it's still on devolopment. sometimes I have to make some changes in other tables wich are not part of the sync group.

Comment: Hi @Z.Maz,  can you try manually sync the tables?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue yes I try it, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this type of issue recently. Issue does not lie with the Azure SQL Data sync.

We used to think the same, that Azure SQL Data Sync starts having issues automatically from time to time. We checked the deployment to see how it is written, and added the below parameter.

Fix: Add the following parameter in the `dacpac` deployment. (It is the `dacpac` that is getting deployed via the SQLPackage Utility.)

```
/p:DropDmlTriggersNotInSource=false
```

This Worked like a charm, and I have not faced any issues after adding this yet.